# Trying to understand Haskell's => vs defining the types

Tags: haskell, type-constraints

In Haskell, why would you define a function with a type constraint:

```
ghci> :t (==)  
(==) :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

Rather than defining it so it's type was:

```
ghci> :t (==)  
(==) :: Eq -> Eq -> Bool
```

Comment: hese two statements are not equal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wouldn't do the second version because you'd get a compile error. `Eq` is not a type, it's a typeclass. You can't use a typeclass in places where a type is required.

If you did define your own type `MyEq` and then define a function `==` with the type `MyEq -> MyEq -> Bool`, the expression `"hello" == "hello"` would be invalid because `"hello"` is a value of type String and not of type MyEq. Since there is no subtyping in haskell a value couldn't be of type String and of type MyEq at the same time.

So if you want to define a function that can accept values of different types which meet certain conditions, you need type classes.

Comment: To follow up to that, see the error you get from running `let a :: Eq -> Eq -> Bool ; a b c = b == c ; in a 2 2` in ghci.

Comment: Thanks guys, that straightens things out!

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell, a "type" can only have a single specific set of possible values
that does not overlap with any other type.
There is no such thing as one type being "a different kind of"
or "a subtype of" another type.

When we want polymorphism, i.e., functions that can apply to more than
one type, we can specify that by using a type variable in the type
signature of the function.

But a type variable can refer to *any*
type at all. We don't always know how to define our function
for absolutely every type. For example, the `(>)`
function only makes sense for types whose elements are
comparable. The compiler will reject
a function whose type signature is too general, in order
to help us avoid writing gibberish.

In your example, `Eq` is not a type. It is a
*typeclass* - a name for a set of types. We declare
typeclass names using the `class` keyword, and
add types into the class using the `instance`
keyword. The purpose of a typeclass is to be used in a
constraint to limit
the scope of a type variable.

The Haskell approach to types and polymorphism is based on the
"Hindley-Milner type system". It is an extremely precise
yet very expressive way of describing data that makes it
easier to give the compiler a huge amount of intelligence 
about the types in your program. That intelligence helps
the compiler to infer types automatically, to give you
a lot of help in getting your program correct, and to optimize
the compiled result, among other benefits.

But be careful - it is very different than the way types are
used in OOP, which may be what you are used to. There is usually no
direct translation between an OO program and a Haskell program.
You have to think about the task in a different way right from
the start. Be especially careful not to confuse Haskell's concepts
of "class" and "instance" with the completely different way those
words are used in OOP.

Comment: "it is very different than the way types are used in OOP", I disagree. Haskell typeclasses are really like "abstract classes" or "interfaces" in OOP, and I suspect some vtable is passed along with the arguments to a polymorphic function for the runtime dispatch to take place.