# Difference between -> and => symbols. What do they mean?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, when we talk type declaration.

I've seen both `->` and `=>`.

As an example: I can make my own type declaration.

```
addMe :: Int -> Int -> Int
addMe x y = x + y
```

And it works just fine.

But if we take a look at `:t sqrt` we get:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

At what point do we use `=>` and when do we use `->`? 
When do we use "fat arrow" and when do we use "thin arrow"?

Comment: `=>` is for a *type constraint*, an arrow `(->)` is a type constructor for a function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so if I wanted my addMe to take a type constraint how would I go about it?

Comment: See also [how to read haskell type signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47803288/791604) and [The meaning of <= vs. => in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37505024/791604).

Comment: Also see [Trying to understand Haskell's => vs defining the types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136133/trying-to-understand-haskells-vs-defining-the-types)

Answer (score 22):

`->` is for explicit functions. I.e. when `f` is something that can be written in an expression of the form `f x`, the signature must have one of these arrows in it<sup>†</sup>. Specifically, the type of `x` (the **argument**) must appear to the left of a `->` arrow.

It's best to not think of `=>` as a function arrow at all, at least at first<sup>‡</sup>. It's an *implication arrow* in the logical sense: **if** `a` is a type with the **property** `Floating a`, then it follows that the signature of `sqrt` is `a -> a`.

For your `addMe` example, which is a function with two arguments, the signature must always have the form `x -> y -> z`. *Possibly* there can also be a `q =>` in front of that; that doesn't influence the function-ishness, but may have some saying in what particular types are allowed. Generally, such constraints are not needed if the types are already fixed and concrete. Like, you could in principle impose a constraint on `Int`:

```
addMe :: Num Int => Int -> Int -> Int
addMe x y = x + y
```

...but that doesn't really accomplish anything, because everybody *knows* that the particular type `Int` is an instance of the `Num` class. Where you *need* such constraints is when the type is *not* fixed but a type variable (i.e. lowercase), i.e. if the function is polymorphic. You can't just write

```
addMe' :: a -> a -> a
addMe' x y = x + y
```

because that signature would suggest the function works for *any* type `a` whatsoever, but it can't work for all types (how would you add, for example, two strings? ok perhaps not the best example, but how would you *multiply* two strings?)

Hence you need the constraint

```
addMe' :: Num a => a -> a -> a
addMe' x y = x + y
```

This means, you don't care what *exact* type `a` is, but you do require it to be a numerical type. Anybody can use the function with their own type `MyNumType`, but they need to ensure that `Num MyNumType` is fulfilled: then it *follows* that `addMe'` can have signature `MyNumType -> MyNumType -> MyNumType`.

The way to ensure this is to either use a standard type which you know to be numerical, for instance `addMe' 5.9 3.7 :: Double` would work, or give an *instance declaration* for your custom type and the [`Num` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num). Only do the latter if you're sure it's a good idea; usually the standard num types are all you'll need.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Note that the arrow may not be *visible* in the signature: it's possible to have a type synonym for a function type, for example when `type IntEndofunc = Int -> Int`, then `f :: IntEndofunc; f x = x+x` is ok. But you can think of the typedef as essentially just a syntactic wrapper; it's still the same type and does have the arrow in it.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>It so happens that logical implication and function application can be seen as two aspects of the same mathematical concept. Furthermore, GHC actually implements class constraints as function arguments, so-called *dictionaries*. But all this happens behind the scenes, so if anything they're *implicit* functions. In standard Haskell, you will never see the LHS of a `=>` type as the type of some actual argument the function is applied to.</sub>

Comment: Some months ago, I ran into the surprising (to me) fact that with `RankNTypes`, it's possible that matching on and then immediately reapplying a `newtype` constructor may not be a no-op. I don't remember the details, but it had to do with the change in a type argument leading to a change in the type of a class constraint under the newtype and therefore an actual change in the way the wrapped value had to use the passed dictionary. I can dig it up if you're interested; I believe it was in a rejected PR to `primitive` and had something to do with traversing arrays.

Answer (score 13):

The "thin arrow" is used for function types (`t1 -> t2` being the type of a function that takes a value of type `t1` and produces a value of type `t2`).

The "fat arrow" is used for type constraints. It separates the list of type constraints on a polymorphic function from the rest of the type. So given `Floating a => a -> a`, we have the function type `a -> a`, the type of a function that can take arguments of any type `a` and produces a result of that same type, with the added constraint `Floating a`, meaning that the function can in fact only be used with types that implement the `Floating` type class.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example: `show :: Show a => a -> String` can convert a value of any type `a` to a `String`, but only if the type `a` implements `Show`.

Comment: Let's say I want to change my addMe function, so it would only take floats, how would I go about it?

Comment: @John Only `Float`s specifically or any type that implements `Floating`?

Comment: Just, two floating numbers, then added and returned. like my addMe is already doing. Just want to try to specify types to my function. :)

Comment: @John I didn't understand that response, so I'm just going to answer both possibilities. To add two `Float`s, the type would be `addMe :: Float -> Float -> Float`. To work with any type that implements `Floating`, it would be `addMe :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`.

Answer (score 0):

the `->` is the constructor of functions and the `=>` is used to constraints, a sort of "interface" in Haskell called typeclass.

A little example:

```
sum :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum x y = x + y
```

that function only allows Int types, but if you want a huge int or a small int, you probably want Integer, and how to tell it to use both?

```
sum2 :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
sum2 x y = x + y
```

now if you try to do:

```
sum2 3 1.5
```

it will give you an error

also, you may want to know if two data are equals, you want:

```
equals :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
equals x y = x == y
```

now if you do:

```
3 == 4
```

that's ok

but if you create:

```
data T = A | B

equals A B
```

it will give to you:

```
error:
    • No instance for (Eq T) arising from a use of ‘equals’
    • In the expression: equals A B
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = equals A B
```

if you want for that to work, you must just do:

```
data T = A | B deriving Eq

equals A B

False
```